# How to vlookup a value when the lookup_value is linked to another tab?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet with three tabs.  In the first tab, i have a column with 4 different employee ID.

On second tab, n the first column, I have different employee ID numbers including some from the first tab;  and in second columns I have employee names associated with these ID

In third tab, the first column links employee ID from the first tab. I want to create a second column with people from the first tab and employee names from the second tab.

My question - How do I vlookup employee names from the second tab, when my employee ID is linked to first tab ? With simple vlookup, it will create an N/A. I don't want to hard code the employee IDs, because I want to make sure my employees ID are always being updated.

Comment: Post some sample data as screenshots so we can get a better idea of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

*You need combination of INDEX & MATCH to lookup Names from Second TAB, associated with IDs from First TAB.*

*Index & Match is faster and better then Vlookup.*

[image]

- Formula in Sheet 3 cell `K37`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!H37:H40,MATCH(Sheet1!E37,Sheet2!G37:G40,0),1),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- Since Employee Ids are identical in both Sheet 1 & Sheet 3, therefore instead of `Match(Sheet1!E37` you may use `Match(J37`.

---

- If you want to use VLOOKUP then, this is the formula:

  ```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!E37,Sheet2!G37:H40,2,FALSE),"")
  ```
- `IFERROR`, avoids the #N/A error.
- Adjust sheet name & cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much Rajesh..

Comment: Hi @Nigela,, glad to help U,, now if you feel you may Up vote as well as [accept this as answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: what if the sheet 1 numbers are combined with letters for example: alpha(E001), gamma(E002), epsilon( E003), lala(E004), what formula would I use ?

Comment: @Nigela, it work unless in every Sheet are not different,, formula searches by match Alpha to Alpha !

Comment: Thank you Rajesh

Comment: @Nigela,, glad to help U,,, keep asking & you may Up vote this ☺